# Option select menu, detect if the 1st option is selected, and not on the value of the 1st option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run some code based on a select option, but not on the option value,
but rather if it's the first option or not. this is because the code will be used globally and the option values will be different according to which product page the user is on.
my pseudo code:

```
if ( the first option.select 'selected' ) {
run some code;
    } else { 
run some other code;
}
```

a typical select menu on this project looks like this:

```
<select name="id[1]" id="attrib-1">
  <option value="20" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
  <option value="212" >Green</option>
  <option value="208">Yellow</option>
  <option value="210">Orange</option>
  <option value="219">Pink</option>
</select>
```

thanks y'all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var select = document.getElementById('attrib-1');

select.onchange = function () {
    if (this.selectedIndex === 0) {
        // run some code...
    } else {
        // run some other code...
    }
}
```

Reference: [HTMLSelectElement - Web API Interfaces | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#Properties)

Comment: Good one. You probably want to listen to the `change` event.

Comment: @BlackSheep True, but the OP is probably already doing that. Will add.

Comment: this works except i cannot use ID's as the ID's will all be different from page to page

Comment: @TopTomato OK, it'll still work with a class. You just need to select the element(s) you want first.

Comment: @TopTomato: I used an ID because you had one in your example. I don't actually know anything about the rest of your setup, so I can't really help.

Comment: @TopTomato Why did you un-accept this answer? After all, it does answer your question which was about detecting the first element of a `select`. The rest is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#attrib-1").change(function () {
        if ($("#attrib-1 > option:first").is(":selected")) {
            alert("first");
        } else {
            //do other stuff
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ergec/Mf62M/

or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#attrib-1").change(function () {
        if ($("#attrib-1").prop("selectedIndex") === 0) {
            alert("first");
        } else {
            //do other stuff
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why the `document.ready` wrapper? The OP doesn't sound like a newbie :)

Comment: @rvighne these answers are not only for OPs, a newbie may come from google

Comment: Well, it should be noted that there is no need to create an object and then using `prop` for reading the property, `this.selectedIndex` makes more sense. Also teaching `this` keyword to _newbies_ can be helpful.